System-Restore: How to use the installed Windows instance like a VM?
How to use the installed Windows instance like a VM?
e.g. using vmware we can restore and resume the vm back in time
I wonder if it is possible with actual hard drive installed windows instance
I know system restore in windows but I am looking something like VM preserve and restore state in hard drive

I've never personally used it, but perhaps https://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze

@jamesdlin maybe this can be feature request for windows or vmware, functionality to take snapshot/restore actual hard drive, system restore restores pc back in time but not as user friendly as vmware workstation.

Maybe for Windows.  That doesn't make sense as a feature request for VMware products unless you plan to convert your physical machine to a virtual one.

Already submitted to windows

Your question is flawed. In a VM, every time an instance is made, the file or files representing the old instance remain unchanged and new files are created. The analogy in a physical machine would involve having to install a new drive or drives for each instance. The new drive(s) would then contain only changes.

@DavidAnderson having to install a new drive or drives for each instance thats bad design, system-restore doesn't create any drives when creating restore point, have no grasp of the underlying mechanisms how vm works but that can be a simple folder on HDD, I mean in possible future version

Preserving and restoring should be feature of the windows os but I see that it is not yet implemented or no os has it or its there but I have not found it. Also the virtualbox/vmware itself is not an os. its a software that runs on top of os.

Only option I found is to make image of the hard drive and feed it to virtualization software such as virtualbox or vmware or hyper-V.
Once I make the image of the hard drive I can

Load it in vm vmware, virtualbox, hyper-v
Load in cloud aws, azure and use it from anywhere in the world

VMware VCenter converter - direct download
Startwid V2V Converter / P2V Migrator 
Sysinternals Disk2chd
VCenter converter seems the best choice

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If you mean how to return the system to exactly the state it was in previously, here are two ways to do so.

Make a complete drive image. There are many effective tools to do so, such as free DriveImage XML, Macrium Reflect Free, and numerous alternatives. [Neither System Restore nor Windows Backup record and restore everything.]
When the image is restored to the drive, it is in exactly the state when imaged (barring clock time). This really is an essential step before making any major changes to a drive, such as changing partitions, and to allow recovery from a dead drive.

Make the drive read only. This can be done by burning a DVD with the state of the machine as you would want it, as if recovering from Hibernation.
Every time the machine shuts down, after reboot, it reloads the state from DVD. A similar system might be used in schools, where after shutdown, the PC boots from a network image, so the next student starts with a clean slate [though one would not use a slate, because of chalk dust ;-) ]


